# Can't redirect on js + Flask

Tags: javascript, python, redirect, flask-login

I have in Flask url for logout

```
@app.route('/logout', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def logout():

    leave_room(str(current_user.code), sid = current_user.name, namespace='/')
    socketio.emit('left_user', current_user.name, room=str(current_user.code))
    db.session.delete(Users.query.filter_by(name=current_user.name).first())
    db.session.commit()
    logout_user()

    flash('You are logged out', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

If i click link below in html that's work

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-center" href = '/logout'>Exit</a>
```

I have 1-8 players in flask room, and after end of the game, all from this room must be logged out and redirected to login page. I emit from server task  by sockets but code below shows 401 Unauthorized instead login page

```
socket.on('leave', function(msg) {
    window.location.href = 'http://my.site.ip.adress:8080/logout';            
    });
```

How to solve this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing @login_required

Now /logout looks like that:

```
@app.route('/logout', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

    def logout():

        if current_user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            leave_room(str(current_user.code), sid = current_user.name, namespace='/')
            socketio.emit('left_user', current_user.name, room=str(current_user.code))
            db.session.delete(Users.query.filter_by(name=current_user.name).first())
            db.session.commit()
            logout_user()

        flash('You are logged out', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```